# What is the mechanism for lexical scope binding inside object methods (Javascript)?

Tags: javascript, scope, arrow-functions

I'm experiencing a major brain freeze here understanding arrow functions and lexical scope: I read through all of Kyle Simpson's 'You don't know JS' some time ago, and I thought I understood scope and context pretty well.  But I'm just not understanding how arrow function lexical scope applies to objects -- I've been working with classes in React, and there it's always clear that the `this` that the arrow function bound to was the class.

For instance, in this example (from https://medium.com/tfogo/advantages-and-pitfalls-of-arrow-functions-a16f0835799e)

```
 let obj = {
      myVar: 'foo',

      myFunc: function() { 
        console.log(this.myVar)  

        setTimeout(() => {
          console.log(this.myVar)
        }, 1000)
      }
    }
```

The arrow function should bind `this` correctly, obviating doing a `bind`.  But this is from lexical scope?  In what sense? Because the next scope is that of the function `myFunc` and this function's lexical parent scope is `obj`?

But then they give this example

```
let obj = {
  myVar: 'foo',

  myFunc: () => { 
    console.log(this.myVar)  
  }
}
obj.myFunc() // undefined
```

where correct binding of `this` does not happen.  Is this because there is no function surrounding the arrow function, and so the next lexical scope is the global context?

To sum it up: is it true that the 'lexical scope' here is simply that same lexical scope defined by functions, and that `this` with arrow functions is simply to look for the parent of the next containing function?

I promise you I understood this (or thought I did) a while ago, but 'use it or lose it', I guess --

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An arrow function has the same lexical-scoping rules as all other functions, except when it comes to `this`. When you define an arrow function, it captures what `this` is right now, at definition time, and uses that forever. Whichever value is available as this`in the lexical context of the arrow function's definition is the permanent value of`this` within the arrow function.

One way to think about it: **if I ended this arrow function definition, and the immediately used `this` outside the definition, what `this` value would that be?**

In your second case, consider one additional property:

```
let obj = {
  myVar: 'foo',

  myFunc: () => { 
    console.log(this.myVar)  
  },

  myOtherVar: this.myVar
}
```

We definitely except `myOtherVar` to be `undefined`, because as you're building this object, `this` is `window` which has no `myVar` property. It's just the same for the arrow function: it permanently adopts a `this` of `window`, so `this.myVar` is undefined.

Comment: Thanks -- I think it's coming back to me now.  So it's not so much 'lexical scope' but what `this` is *at the moment the arrow function is defined/parsed*?  So the only reason the first function works, is because `this` has a value at runtime of `obj` at the moment the arrow function is defined, and it has this value because of the call `obj.myFunc`?

Comment: @Cerulean Correct: in the first case, `myFunc` is a non-arrow function (myFunc: function() {....`). The arrow function is defined within the execution of that non-arrow func, whose execution has  a `this` value distinct from what `this` is when defining the object.

Comment: Just want to say this is a fantastic explanation, the best on SO where questions about scope and `this` tend to be downvoted or simply told that arrow functions always keep parent scope without explaining how `function(){}` is able to capture the lexical `this` of a plain object parent while an arrow function isn't. The same distinction is glossed over or omitted by every tutorial I looked through for an answer to this question. Thinking of it from time of definition clarifies everything.

Answer (score 1):

> But this is from lexical scope? In what sense?

In the sense that it is the same value as `this` has inside the function where the arrow function is defined.

Both `console.log(this.myVar)` use the same `this`

> Because the next scope is that of the function myFunc and this function's lexical parent scope is obj?

`myFunc`'s parent scope is irrelevant. It isn't an arrow function. It gets its `this` value from where it is called.

---

> where correct binding of this does not happen.

`this` is the same as the parent function. The object literal has no effect on it.

If we add another console.log, then the two are (again) referencing the same value.

```
console.log(this.myVar)
let obj = {
  myVar: 'foo',

  myFunc: () => { 
    console.log(this.myVar)  
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First keep in mind the definition of arrow function

*An arrow function does not have its own this; the this value of the enclosing execution context is used ([mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions#No_separate_this))*

---

```js
let obj = {
  myVar: 'foo',
  myFunc: function() { 
    console.log(this.myVar)  
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log(this.myVar)
    }, 1000)
  }
}
obj.myFunc();
```

> The arrow function should bind this correctly, obviating doing a bind.
>   But this is from lexical scope? In what sense? Because the next scope
>   is that of the function myFunc and this function's lexical parent
>   scope is obj?

here the enclosing function of the `setTimeout` callback is a method on the object itself so it will inherit the current instance, as you said.

---

```js
let obj = {
  myVar: 'foo',
  myFunc: () => { 
    console.log(this.myVar)  
  }
}
obj.myFunc() // undefined
```

> where correct binding of this does not happen. Is this because there
>   is no function surrounding the arrow function, and so the next lexical
>   scope is the global context?

in this second scenario the method declared on the instance uses an arrow function so the `this` will be inherited from the enclosing function but since no function wrap your object will be `Window`